# How to multiple shell scripts passing with arguments

Tags: bash, shell

I have scripts a.sh and b.sh in which i have pass the ip as argument.

I tried running it as

```
sh -x a.sh 172.19.57.21 & b.sh 172.19.57.21 &
```

But I see only first script runs.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `sh -x a.sh 172.19.57.21 & b.sh 172.19.57.21 &`:

- `sh -x a.sh 172.19.57.21` is one command, `&` sends it to background immediately
- `b.sh 172.19.57.21` is another command, again `&` puts it in background

The problem seems to me is that the script `b.sh` is not executable and as you are not running it as an argument to shell (unlike `a.sh`), it is failed in the `PATH` search.

You can run `b.sh` as shell's argument as well e.g:

```
sh a.sh 172.19.57.21 & sh b.sh 172.19.57.21 &
```

Or if both scripts are executables and have proper shebang:

```
./a.sh 172.19.57.21 & ./b.sh 172.19.57.21 &
```

---

I would recommend a wrapper to get the argument IP address once, and call required scripts from the wrapper, something like a tiny function would do:

```
wrapper() {
    /path/to/a.sh "$@" &
    /path/to/b.sh "$@" &
}
```

Now, you can just do e.g.:

```
wrapper 172.19.57.21
```

Answer (score 0):

use `;` between commands like

```
sh -x a.sh 172.19.57.21 &; sh -x b.sh 172.19.57.21 &
```

Comment: `;` is not necessary after `&`, see "Pipelines" chapter in bash(1) manpage.